# What accounts for the time difference when I ping a remote server?

Tags: networking, ping

The outage earlier had me doubting the quality of my own connection. Which led me to ping SE and I saw something that I cannot explain possibly due to a gap in my knowledge.

```
ping -c4 wordpress.stackexchange.com
```

I get 4 pretty standard pings and the following summary:

```
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 12121ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.612/71.505/82.041/12.522 ms
```

The ping time accounts for maybe 2% of that total (12,121 ms) so what is the rest and what does it tell me?

If it makes any difference, ping sent from an Ubuntu PC with a fibre connection in the UK.

Comment: I'm talking about: time 12,121ms

Comment: Maybe a super slow DNS lookup?

Comment: Is there any chance you made a typo when you originally entered the ping command and you really did a `ping -i4 wordpress.stackexchange.com`, and then maybe ctrl-c cancelled it after 4 pings? Waiting 4 seconds between pings for 4 pings could account for this.

Comment: No, that was a cut-down copy and paste from the terminal.